# accessory shift by index list of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I would know why my tableviewcell's accessory is moved a little bit to the left when I set up an index list and how to avoid it.

Comment: If you could share some code, would help to suggest the solution

Comment: I only use the standard accessory of uitableviewcell. But when I've implemented an index list (like Contact app) with - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView . The accessory arrow is shift to the left (in order to display well the index list i think). I just find a way to avoid this comportement.